# sbt-assembly: deduplication different file contents found

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I have problem with sbt , when i run this `sbt json-config clean assembly`
I got these errors:

```
[error] (myapp-api/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/teaddict/.ivy2/cache/cglib/cglib-nodep/jars/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar:asm-license.txt
[error] /home/teaddict/.ivy2/cache/org.mockito/mockito-all/jars/mockito-all-1.10.19.jar:asm-license.txt
```

I changed my `Build.scala` like that and tried every option but still I got same error.

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly <<= (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
  {
    case PathList("net", "sf", "cglib", _ @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last.toLowerCase == "asm-license.txt" => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("asm-license.txt") => MergeStrategy.rename
    case PathList("asm-license.txt") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last == "asm-license.txt" => MergeStrategy.discard
    case "asm-license.txt" => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => old(x)
  }
},
```

Comment: I think the only line actually used is case `PathList("asm-license.txt") => MergeStrategy.rename` , try changing it to `case PathList("asm-license.txt") => MergeStrategy.discard`

Comment: tried but now working :/

Comment: In this precise case, I suppose you only need mockito for testing and not in assembly, maybe you could scope your mockito dependency to be tests only ? :
`libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19" % "test"`

Comment: how can i do it :)

Comment: `libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19" % "test"`

Comment: the problem is when i compile it, it runs all tests too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132474/discussion-between-c4stor-and-tea-addict).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("net", "sf", "cglib", ps @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "asm-license.txt" => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x =>
    val old = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    old(x)
}
```